# UNION ALL ordering the end results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is producing results successfully. However, results are sequential and I would like to order them by a column in both tables called `clicks`

```
(SELECT women_id, title, body FROM women ORDER BY women_id DESC LIMIT 5) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT man_id, title, body FROM man ORDER BY man_id DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Right now it gives results like this:

```
women 41124
women 124
women 12
women 2
women 1
men 3455434
men 1233
men 135
men 23
men 1
```

I need it to give final results like this:

```
men 3455434
women 41124
men 1233
men 135
women 124
men 23
women 12
women 2
women 1
men 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bring in the `clicks` into the `UNION`-ed data set, add `ORDER BY`, and then project the unnecessary column out with another `SELECT`, like this:

```
SELECT person_id, title, body FROM ((
   (SELECT women_id as person_id, title, body, clicks FROM women ORDER BY women_id DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
   (SELECT man_id as person_id, title, body, clicks FROM man ORDER BY man_id DESC LIMIT 5)
) ORDER BY clicks DESC) data
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this.  It seems 4 or 5 others have had the same idea - this is the only one that adds in the 'clicks' column and orders by it though

Comment: @Ochi To project out the `clicks` column, which OP did not want to see in the output.

Comment: I assumed so that it still returned the original 3 columns

Comment: I got the error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @AmyNeville The query was missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Still seems to be having that error. Could it be not compatible with mysql?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by adding AS before the "data" temporary table name - it seemed to want an alias. Ty very very much for your help!

Comment: @AmyNeville You are welcome! It was an order of parentheses, after all. Here is a [small demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18e3c/3).

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    (SELECT women_id, title, body, clicks FROM women ORDER BY women_id DESC LIMIT 5)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT man_id, title, body, clicks FROM man ORDER BY man_id DESC LIMIT 5)
)
ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

just add order by at the end and job done

Comment: clicks is still not a valid column within that UNION

Comment: he said there is such a column

Comment: You've added it in now - at time of posting you hadn't included it in the UNIONs

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    (SELECT women_id AS ID, title, body FROM women LIMIT 5) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT man_id  AS ID, title, body FROM man LIMIT 5)
)
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: This one looks like it might fit well but it said "Every derived table must have its own alias" as error